# Why is inner padding only applied on the right?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

**MCVE**

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.minsize(200, 100)
inner_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(root, text='inner_frame')
inner_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

button = ttk.Button(inner_frame, text='this is a button')
button.grid(row=0, column=0)

# this does not work as expected
inner_frame.grid_configure(ipadx=20)

root.mainloop()
```

**Output**

[image]

**Question**

Why is the inner padding for `inner_frame` only applied on the right? How do I apply it on both sides?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, `ipadx` isn't failing. It's working as designed, it's just that the way it works isn't very intuitive, especially when you apply it to a frame.

To better visualize what is happening, lets apply the `ipadx` value to the button rather than the frame. That way we can see the padding relative to the label on the button.

For example, add two buttons instead of one. Give one an `ipadx` of 20, and give the other an `ipadx` of 0.

```
button1 = ttk.Button(inner_frame, text='this is a button')
button2 = ttk.Button(inner_frame, text='this is a button')

button1.grid(row=0, column=0, ipadx=20)
button2.grid(row=1, column=0, ipadx=0)
```

Notice that the button with `ipadx=20` is wider, and the extra space is inside the button rather than as a margin surrounding the button.

[image: screenshot of two buttons]

The same thing is happening with `inner_frame`: when it is added to its parent, the extra space is being added *inside* the frame, effectively making `inner_frame` wider. You can't see it because it's added to the empty space already inside the frame.

Here's the important part: if you add a widget to `inner_frame`, `grid` doesn't know anything about the `ipadx` values applied to `inner_frame` -- that `ipadx` option only applies to `inner_frame` and its *parent*, not its children. At the point of adding widgets inside of `inner_frame`, `grid` only knows that `inner_frame` is X pixels wide.

To illustrate, we can add a label to the button, similar to how your original code adds a button to the frame. (note: we'll turn geometry propagation off so that it doesn't cause the button to shrink).

```
button1.grid_propagate(False)
label = ttk.Label(button1, text="x")
label.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

You should see a window that looks something like this:

[image: screenshot of label inside button]

See how the "x" is at the far left edge of the button? That is because it doesn't know anything about the `ipadx` value applied to its parent. All it knows is that the button is X pixels widget, and that it's supposed to be on the left edge of the button.

That is what's happening with you original frame and button - the button is being added inside the frame, making use of all of the space inside the frame.

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly, and I don't know if this is a bug, your problem is solved by making the column containing the button expand past its minimum horizontal size.

The minimum horizontal size of column 0 in the inner frame is the horizontal size of its content, which is the button.

If you add a `inner_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)`, then the internal padding works as expected:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

inner_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(root_frame, text="inner_frame")
inner_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

inner_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

button = ttk.Button(inner_frame, text="this is a button")
button.grid(row=0, column=0)

# this works expected:
inner_frame.grid_configure(ipadx=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Note that `grid_configure` changes column 0 by default, so here we're adding internal padding to the cells in column 0.

I do not know exactly why this happens. It is not mentioned in the Tcl grid docs (http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/grid.htm#M13).

Interestingly, this link does mention some special case around size of the frame using internal padding (low down the page, in the "Internal Padding" section): https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html

> The difference can be subtle. Let's say you have a frame that's 20x20, and specify normal (external) padding of 5 pixels on each side. The frame will request a 20x20 rectangle (its natural size) from the geometry manager. Normally, that's what it will be granted, so it'll get a 20x20 rectangle for the frame, surrounded by a 5-pixel border.
>
> With internal padding, the geometry manager will effectively add the extra padding to the widget when figuring out its natural size, as if the widget has requested a 30x30 rectangle. If the frame is centered, or attached to a single side or corner (using "sticky"), you'll end up with a 20x20 frame with extra space around it. If however the frame is set to stretch (i.e. a "sticky" value of "we", "ns", or "nwes") it will fill the extra space, resulting in a 30x30 frame, with no border.

But it is confusingly written, and I can't fully understand what they mean (or even if they are correct in modern Python). If someone knows what that paragraph above means, by all means comment below and let us know!

### Adding internal padding to the frame as a whole

You can add internal padding by using styles or passing it directly as an argument to the frame's constructor:

```py
ttk.LabelFrame(root, text="inner", padding=(20, 0))
```

The padding value there can take either:

- One value, for padding on all sides
- Two values, for x and y (in that order)
- Four values, for padding starting at the left and going clockwise.

Comment: Thanks for digging! I read that paragraph, too, and it left me confused. What if `inner_frame` has multiple columns, though? (Also, I simplified the code in my question, you may want to adjust your answer.)

Comment: `grid_configure` changes column 0 by default, so by doing `grid_configure(ipadx=20)` you've configured the internal padding of column 0.

If you want to add more column paddings, you'll have to do so for each, and also adjust the weight so it is non-zero.

Comment: @JoseSalvatierra: no, `grid_configure` doesn't change column 0. You must be thinking if `grid_columnconfigure`. `grid_configure` doesn't configure a row or column, it configures a slave. You  wrote _"so here we're adding internal padding to the cells in column 0."_ which is not correct. It's adding internal padding to the widget as a whole, not to a specific column.

Answer (score -1):

So far I have figured out that using `padding=...` in the `LabelFrame` constructor produces the correct result.

If you delete the line

```
inner_frame.grid_configure(ipadx=20)
```

and use

```
inner_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(root, text='inner_frame', padding=[20, 0])
```

or alternatively

```
inner_frame['padding'] = [20, 0]
```

the result looks like this:

[image]

I have no clue why using `ipadx` through `grid_configure` does not work as expected.

Comment: Internal and external padding work differently. When using external padding, for example, any background colour or styling of the frame will not be applied to the external padding area. You can think of it as a transparent border.

Comment: @JoseSalvatierra yes, but `padding=...` seems to pad internally, as desired. No?

Comment: It is not internal padding, it is a border on the left side of the frame. It looks the same here, but try adding a background colour to the frame and you'll see the difference!

Comment: Actually, my apologies--the `padding` parameter you've used here is unrelated to `grid`. So you're right, it's internal padding, but on the frame itself and not in a particular column.

Comment: @JoseSalvatierra yes, I checked by adding a background color. Still, it would be nice to know what the problem with `ipadx` / grid is here.

Comment: Yep, not sure why it needs the weight change to apply internal padding!